# Phone call intent doesnt work - Xiaomi phone

Tags: java, android, android-intent

When you tap the contact number layout it is supposed to make a phone call, but when I tap I get a blank screen for a second and then screen goes to rootview. The log shows the contact number correctly and I have added permissions.

I am using a xiaomi redmi 4 phone, dual sim. If i change the intent to Intent.ACTION_DIAL it dials fine but I want to make call.

permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

call intent code

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail, container, false);

    initializeDetailScreen(rootView);
    setValuesDetailScreen();

    mScrollView.setFillViewport(true);

    mTapToCallLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            String contactNumber = "";               
            try {
                contactNumber =  (String) mContactJSONObj.get(Constants.CONTACT_TEL);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.v(LOG_TAG,"There is an error. ");
            }
            Log.v(LOG_TAG,"Contact number is: "+contactNumber);
            callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + contactNumber));
            startActivity(callIntent);
        }
    });
    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: What targetSdkVersion are you using and what version of device are you running?

Comment: targetSdkVersion 23 and device is android version 7.1.2 N2G47H

Comment: What do the logs say when you try that intent? Do you ask for runtime permission before you try to make the call?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: it worked, problem was runtime permissions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are targeting an SDK of 23 and this requires you to implement runtime permissions in order to successfully use Intent.ACTION_CALL.

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html